# Exclude elemental block for a particular subsite

Tags: php, silverstripe-4

Is it possible to exclude silverstripe elemental blocks for a particular subsite?
Or, to specify the allowed elements for individual subsites?

Either in config, or by using a function/extension...

Answer (score 0):

No, that functionality doesn't currently exist - unless you declare specific page types that are exclusive to different subsites, and *only* use those page types on their respective subsites. You can then declare the allowed elements based on those page types.